# Passing 2 strings via the delegate

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I'm wondering how I can pass 2 strings through my delegate?  I want to pass it from viewcontroller2 (SelectStationViewController) to viewcontroller1 (SubGabViewController).

I have it currently working, just passing 1 string (NSString *test).

Here's the code I have set up:

```
// in SelectStationViewController.h
@protocol SelectStationViewControllerDelegate;
...
@interface ... {
    id <SelectStationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SelectStationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol SelectStationViewControllerDelegate
- (void)selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:(NSString *)selectedStationName;
@end

// in SelectStationViewController.m
NSString *test = [[copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hash"];
[delegate selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:test];

// in SubGabViewController.h
@interface...<SelectStationViewControllerDelegate>

// in SubGabViewController.m

// set selectedStationName as currentStationName
- (void)selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:(NSString *)selectedStationName
{
    NSLog(@"selectedStationName is = %@", selectedStationName);
    [self setCurrentStationName:selectedStationName];
}
```

In order to pass 2 strings to the delegate, would I do something like this?

```
// in SelectStationViewController.m
NSString *test = [[copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hash"];
NSString *test2 = [[copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"linehash"];
[delegate selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:test];
[delegate selectLineViewControllerDidFinish:test2];
```

and then have another function set up like this?

```
- (void)selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:((NSString *)selectedStationName;
- (void)selectLineViewControllerDidFinish:((NSString *)selectedLineName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a delegate method in SubGabViewController that gets 2 strings in its params instead of one and call it from SelectStationViewController :

```
- (void) functionName:(NSString*)str1 string2:(NSString*)str2;

[delegate functionName:stringtogive1 string2:stringtogive2];
```

That's all folks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you could pass an array of strings through your delegate method, like this:

```
- (void)selectStationViewControllerDidFinish:(NSArray *)selectedStations;
```

Whether you have one or a hundred values to pass over, they can be passed with this one simple method.